# $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|f({1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-f(\mu)|> \epsilon)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be independent, identically distributed real random variables where $E(X_n)=: \mu$ and $E(X_n^2) < \infty$ and further $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a continuous function.

How can I show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(|f({1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i)-f(\mu)|> \epsilon)=0$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$?

I guess I need to show that there are only finite many $m \in N$ such that $$|f({1 \over m} \sum_{i=1}^mX_i)-f(\mu)|> \epsilon$$ or in other words that
$$|f(\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n} \sum_{i=m}^nX_i)-f(\mu)|<\epsilon$$ for all $n \geq m$.

Can someone give me a hint or some approach?

Comment: Obviously $|f(\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i))-f(\mu)|=0$ but I see no way that this could help me..

Comment: Did you try using Biénaymé-Tchebytchev inequality? Although it's correct only if $f(X_i)$ is positive

Comment: No I just checked it and it looks helpful, thanks. $f$ could be negative though

Comment: just pay attention in using because the random variable must be positive.

Comment: Hm I do get the principle of the BT-inequality but I don't know how to specifically apply it to my problem..

Comment: if $f$ were positive, then you would consider the random variable $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(X_i)$ and apply the theorem to it and this of course holds if the variance of $Y$ exists.

Comment: you just need this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strong law of large numbers shows that

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} \mu$$

almost surely. By the continuity of the function $f$, this implies that

$$f \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} f(\mu)$$

almost surely. Since convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability, we get

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \left| f \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)-f(\mu) \right| > \epsilon \right) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0$$

for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Central limit theorem or law of large numbers?

Comment: @aduh Law of large numbers; thanks.

Comment: Thanks, didn´t fully accept the answer yet as I couldn't figure out how to apply the central limit theorem ;-)

Comment: @Tesla Yeah, sorry about that.